# How can I embed clickable URL hyperlinks in data columns in Contour?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I have a Foundry table that has a column full of URLs, represented as a String type.

I want to make the elements of this column into clickable hyperlinks so that a user using Contour can directly click on the link to take them to the page. How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

This is done by adding the `url` typeclass on the underlying dataset using the dataset-preview application. Contour and Reports will respect this typeclass on its Table board representations of the data.